# Referencing Values within Array Object VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of arrays that I am testing to make sure they work:

For example:

```
Dim LSh As Worksheet
Dim NewPricingArr As Variant
Set LSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lists")
NewPricingArr = LSh.Range(LSh.Cells(2, 1), LSh.Cells(LSh.Cells(LSh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 5))
```

This all works fine.

To test that I am accessing the right data point in the array, I tried to add one of its values into a cell:

```
LSh.Cells(10, 1) = NewPricingArr(1, 5).Value
```

However, this results in an object required error '424'.

Am I referencing it incorrectly?

Comment: Remove the `.Value`. Even better: `LSh.Cells(10, 1).Value = NewPricingArr(1, 5)`.

Comment: Worked. Thanks very much.